# Bash Aliases and Dotfiles

Tags: bash, dotfiles, aliases

I recently came across this `# -*- sh -*-` at the top of a file with aliases in them. It was part of someone's dotfiles inside their bash directory and, until now, I've never seen it before. So, what is this and how is it different than using a shebang? I tried googling alternatives to a shebang, but came up with nothing that gives me a hint as to what the above is. [image: Shebang]

Comment: The shebang is a magic number (essentially) that tells bash that the following script should be interpreted by the specified executable instead of being executed through bash (or whatever the current shell is). More info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87600

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files with alias definitions do *not* need shebang lines, because executing them stand-alone would not add the definitions to the *current* shell, which is the point of alias definitions.

Instead, files with alias definitions must be *sourced* (run in the context of the *current* shell, with `source` or `.`).

Thus, what you're seeing is just an ordinary *comment* that indicates what specific shell (`sh`) the file is designed to be sourced from.